# Creating Tree From Symbol List Based on Symbol Arity in C#

Tags: c#, tree

I am trying to figure out how to create a tree from a list of symbols which have a varying number of arity.  For example, lets say I have the following symbols with the specified arity:

| Symbol | Arity |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 2 |
| D | 0 |
| E | 0 |

and I have the following string representation:

AABCDDEEDED

I am trying to build the following tree:

```
      A
     / \
    A   B
   / \  |
  C   D D
 / \
E   E
```

In this case, the last three symbols (DED) did not need to be used because the tree is already full.

I have already defined by symbols with the specific arity, and each of which contains a property which can hold a list of other symbols; all symbols implement `ISymbol<T>`.  I also can generate the `AABCDDE...` string.

But I am kind of lost on how to get the tree-built.  Is there a name for this kind of tree I am attempting to build?  I wasn't able to find anything specific about varying number of nodes and to build it in this specific way (i.e., build it up layer by layer until all symbols of the current layer have their child populated before going to the next layer).

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  TIA.

[EDIT] Implementations based on @michael-liu suggestion

```cs
var root = GeneCoding![0] as Symbol<T>;
if (root!.Arity == 0)
{
    return root!;
}

var queue = new Queue<Symbol<T>>();
queue.Enqueue(root);

Symbol<T> node;
Symbol<T> current;

foreach (var symbol in GeneCoding!.Skip(1))
{
    node = (Symbol<T>)symbol;
    if (node.Arity != 0)
    {
        queue.Enqueue(node);
    }

    current = queue.Peek();
    current.Nodes.Add(node);
    if (current.Arity == current.Nodes.Count)
    {
        var dequeued = queue.Dequeue();
        if (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(dequeued);
        }
        else
        {
            return dequeued;
        }
    }
}

throw new Exception();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your tree is built layer by layer, I suggest using a queue of nodes. The algorithm would look something like this:

1. Create the `root` node for the first symbol in the string.
2. If `root` has zero arity, then STOP (the tree is complete).
3. Create a `queue` of nodes that initially contains `root`.
4. For each remaining `symbol` in the string:

   1. Create a `node` for `symbol`.
   2. If `node` has non-zero arity, then enqueue `node` at the back of `queue`.
   3. Peek the `current` node at the front of `queue`.
   4. Add `node` as a child of `current`.
   5. If `current` has full arity:

      1. Dequeue `current` from the front of `queue`.
      2. If `queue` is empty, then STOP (the tree is complete).
5. [STOP] Return `root` as the output of the algorithm.

---

Here's a corrected version of the code you posted:

```
var root = (Symbol<T>)GeneCoding![0];
if (root.Arity == 0)
{
    return root;
}

var queue = new Queue<Symbol<T>>();
queue.Enqueue(root);

Symbol<T> node;
Symbol<T> current;

foreach (var symbol in GeneCoding!.Skip(1))
{
    node = (Symbol<T>)symbol;
    if (node.Arity != 0)
    {
        queue.Enqueue(node);
    }

    current = queue.Peek();
    current.Nodes.Add(node);
    if (current.Arity == current.Nodes.Count)
    {
        queue.Dequeue();
        if (queue.Count == 0)
        {
            return root;
        }
    }
}

throw new Exception();
```

Comment: I attempted to implement your solution but there is a problem with symbols being duplicated.  For example, when I am working with the symbol string +a-*abaabba, it work about half way but then it gets to a point where the - symbol is the first item in the queue, but it is also located as one of the nodes under +, instead of just being under the +.  I have updated the OP with the code I wrote based on your suggestion.

Comment: What are the arities of +, -, *, a, and b? What is the expected tree for this string?

Comment: For +, -, and * the arity is 2 and for a/b the arity is 0.

Comment: It seems that the queue does end up with one item which had the proper tree structure but because there are still additional items hanging around with their children filled up (and are a duplicate of the item in the full tree) the code either never ends, because there is always more than 1 item in the queue, for throws an exception (depending on how I structure the code).

Comment: Also, the number of items remaining varies.  For the specific example I gave there were three items left in the queue and the second one was correct.  However, I tried another list (which contained more symbols with arities 0, 1, and 2) and there were four items left in the queue and the third one was the correct, fully populated, tree.

Comment: Toward the end of your code, you have `queue.Enqueue(dequeued);`. This is not part of the algorithm and should be deleted. Also, you should return the root node in the `else`, not the current node.